# regex to exact values from a string

Tags: javascript, regex

I have strings that are formatted like this:

`Size: 1243 MB Amount: 2,239 Value: 1,569 Info: 1Z31LZ`

I can split on `:` and then replace some of the names to get the value, but I'm sure there's gotta be an expression that I can use to get the exact values out.  Ideally it would end up in an array like this `['1243','MB','2,239','1,569','1Z31LZ']`

Any help would be awesome!

Comment: You need MB as a separate element?

Comment: http://www.regexper.com/

Comment: @bagonyi doesn't have to be, but would be nice if it was possible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var parts = "Size: 1243 MB Amount: 2,239 Value: 1,569 Info: 1Z31LZ".match(/^Size: (.+) (.+) Amount: (.+) Value: (.+) Info: (.+)$/g);
```

You get an array like this:

```
["1243", "MB", "2,239", "1,569", "1Z31LZ"]
```

Answer (score 0):

The best I got so far is this:

```
(?!\w+:)([A-Za-z,1-9]+)+
```

You use a negative lookbehind to not match anything that has a colon after it.

The highlighted text is what it matches.

Size: `1243` `MB` Amount: `2,239` Value: `1,569` Info: `1Z31LZ`

**Edit** Forgot a `+`.

And the sanity check to make sure it actually works in Javascript:

```
console.log("Size: 1243 MB Amount: 2,239 Value: 1,569 Info: 1Z31LZ".match(/(?!\w+:)([A-Za-z,1-9]+)+/g));
```

Output:

```
["1243", "MB", "2,239", "1,569", "1Z31LZ"]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
/Size: (\d+) ([A-Za-z]+) Amount: ([\d,]+) Value: ([\d,]+) Info: ([\d\w]+)/
```

I tried to be more restrictive, but I may have excluded something you need, bagonyi's answer will be more versatile.

The information will be in groups 1-5

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
foo="Size: 1243 MB Amount: 2,239 Value: 1,569 Info: 1Z31LZ";
foo.split(/\s*\S*:\s+/).filter(Boolean);
```

returns:

```
["1243 MB", "2,239", "1,569", "1Z31LZ"]
```

This doesn't quite match the output, but you mention it's preferred not to split the "MB".

Answer (score 0):

You can probably use:

```
s = 'Size: 1243 MB Amount: 2,239 Value: 1,569 Info: 1Z31LZ';
m = .split(/[^: ]+: *| +/).filter(Boolean);
//=> ["1243", "MB", "2,239", "1,569", "1Z31LZ"]
```